# jQuery 1.8+ breaks sortable list scrolling inside absolute positioned element with bottom: 0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Using jQuery 1.7.2 I was able to drag sortable elements inside an absolutely positioned element with bottom: 0; But upgrading from jQuery 1.7.2 to 1.8 causes the following jsfiddle to not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/m765z/3/

The container never scrolls. If you switch back to 1.7.2, it scrolls.

I can't find an update in the jQuery changelog, and I'm not finding similar bug reports in jQueryUI.

Trying to figure out why it broke and how to fix it.

Comment: That's really odd. The latest changes are don't seem to do much: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commits/master/ui/jquery.ui.sortable.js

Comment: I would file a bug. I have tried the 1.8.1 version of jquery to see if that fixed it but it doesnt look like it. So file the bug on the jquery ui site.

Comment: It works for me in Chrome (Mac). What browser are you using?

Comment: I just found another case this was not working.  I don't have a fiddle example, but in my app I was seeing strange behavior where a sortable list wasn't scrolling.  This definitely a bug in 1.8.1.  I downgraded to 1.7.1 and it worked fine.  Bizarre.

Comment: Also, they rewrote the whole Sizzle engine this most recent version, and actually introduced a bunch of bugs that were not there before.  We encountered quite a few in our upgrade to 1.8.

Comment: I have opened a ticket with Jquery here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12558

Comment: I tested in Chrome, Canary, Safari, and Firefox on Mac. Also IE 9 on Win 7. Experienced same problem in all browsers in my jsfiddle example. I also opened a bug at jQuery UI: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8564

Comment: Ah yes.  That is the appropriate place to log that ticket.

Comment: I don't know where you're using this, but it works if you take out the "position: absolute;". Do you need that if you have all the edges set to 0?

Comment: Yes, I need position absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be fixed with jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

The scroll works if you remove the 
overflow: auto;

from your css - #wrapper

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have overflow: auto there. Otherwise the div expands, and that's why it looks like it works.

You can see what happens to the div if you remove overflow:auto in this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m765z/34/